# [Android]context.startActvity(intent) throwing ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-12

My use case is to switch from **App1** to **App2** . In App1, I use the **packageManager.getPackageInfo()**  API to check whether the App2 is present or not.
When it returns true, I set the intent with **intent.setPackage(App2)** and trigger the context.startActivity(intent) API.
But there are times when  **context.startActivity(intent)  API** throws **ActivityNotFoundException**: App2 is present in the device. The intent has been set in App2 and android:exported is also set to true.

This issue is happening from **Android 12**. Any inputs be would be highly appreciated!

Comment: post your stacktrace and code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official documentation on how to prepare an Activity to be launched from outside of the app:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters

---

Furthermore there are multiple examples on how to launch an external activity, maybe check out these two examples ([Source for the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-another-application-in-android)):

**[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-another-application-in-android)**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574735/9077356)**

```java
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```